# I can not extract RAR file

Tags: rar

I can not extract RAR file, I tried many tutorials that I found on the internet but no one work.
With right click, says it is not possible to finish extraction

with "unrar x", show this memsage

> "Cannot open archive.rar No files to extract"

I transfer this file 2 times with USB drive, and before that I extracted it on another PC, so I think it is intact.

anyone know the solution?

Comment: include the results for `file archive.rar` and `ls -l archive.rar` in your question please. (cd from commandline to the dir the file is in)

Answer (score 20):

You can install and use the utility `p7zip` (`p7zip-full` and `p7zip-rar`).

`p7zip` is a file archiver that archives with very high compression ratios.

`p7zip-rar` provides a module for `p7zip-full` to
extract `.rar` files.

To install the tool - open a terminal and execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update  

sudo apt-get install p7zip-full p7zip-rar
```

Now you can extract `.rar` files from `nautilus` right-click menu.

Additional information and a list of supported archive formats :

- Unpacking RAR only if `p7zip-rar` package is installed.
- Packing / Unpacking : 7z, ZIP, GZIP, BZIP2, XZ and TAR.
- Unpacking only : APM, ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DEB, DMG, FAT,
  HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, LZMA2, MBR, MSI, MSLZ, NSIS, NTFS, RAR, RPM, SquashFS, UDF,
  VHD, WIM, XAR and Z.

Comment: Then the command to unzip is `7z x <file>`

Comment: `p7zip-rar` is now included in `p7zip-full`, so you only need to `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full`

Answer (score 2):

Unrar does not work, install and use rar:

```
sudo apt install rar
```

and extract files:

```
rar x file.rar
```

Answer (score 1):

install an archive manager like 7zip

for easy installation, I recommend getting synaptic which is GUI manager for your downloads

From terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

from there, search for 7zip and mark for installation and then click apply. This will also make your future installations much easier if you're not accustomed to the command line like me.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easy way to extract password protected rar files in ubuntu or other linux distros is to use the "Xachiver" which is also available in app store